# Scrollup to textarea when keyboard is up

Tags: javascript, scroll, firefox-os

In my ToDo list app, I have a text area that is appended at the end of the list. The problem right now is that when I tap on the textarea, the keboard shows up but the textarea is behind the keyboard and the page doesnt scrollup unless I start typing. As you can imagine, this is not a good UX.

How do I scrollup to the textarea as soon as the keyboard shows up?

**EDIT:** This is an observation in the simulator version 2.0

Comment: give it a try http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: you said keyboard shows up, but which device/platform, please add correxponding tag, so tat u ll get correct response

Comment: @Khaleel As mentioned in the recent edit, this is an observation in the simulator version 2.0. I havent tested it in the device yet.

Comment: Is the text area the last thing on the page?  If it is, perhaps all you need to do is put some line-breaks `<br />` in your HTML after the text area.  That would give the keyboard something else to cover (empty lines), instead of the text area.  In terms of a dynamic list, use something like `txar=document.getElementById("txtarea");` and `txar.insertBefore("NewToDoItem");` to keep the text area at the end of the list, and the line-breaks after the text area.

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim Not a good idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by scrolling to the container's bottom for onClick event:

```
$(document).on("click", "#new_todo_item",function(){  // scroll to bottom when clicked on input textarea
    $("#todo_list_container").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()+$(document).height() }, 1000);
});
```

I had to add up `$(document).height()+$(document).height()` since one height didnt really scroll to the bottom. The downside is that there is no animation now.